How do I open the current file in the default application using Neovim?
In the terminal, I can open a file with its default application using this command:
open example.txt

In some Linux systems, I need to use xdg-open instead of open, like this:
xdg-open example.txt

This will open the text file in Gedit or TextEdit or whatever the default graphical text editor is.
In Vim, I can open the current file in the default application by running this command:
:! open %

The ! runs the command in a shell, and the % gets replaced with the current filename. Sadly, this doesn't work in Neovim, due to a known issue mentioned in the FAQ:

:! AND SYSTEM() DO WEIRD THINGS WITH INTERACTIVE PROCESSES
Interactive commands are supported by :terminal in Nvim. But :! and system() do not support interactive commands, primarily because Nvim UIs use stdio for msgpack communication, but also for performance, reliability, and consistency across platforms (see https://vimhelp.org/gui_x11.txt.html#gui-pty).
See also #1496 and #8217.

I know I can run :lua vim.ui.open("example.txt") to open example.txt in the default application, but how can I open the current file in the default application in Neovim, without having to type out the filename?

How about :terminal open %?

You can use vim.fn.expand("%") to get the filename of the current buffer, so putting it together with vim.ui.open() you get
:lua vim.ui.open(vim.fn.expand("%"))


Also possible is vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0) instead of vim.fn.expand("%"), they act a little bit differently but that's also a possibility
